# Windows Service starting issue in c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wcf

When i try to start a windows service after install using nssm then is shows me below error

[image: Window Service Error]

**Added Code**

```
#region Private Members 

private Timer timer1 = null; 

#endregion

#region Constructor

public Service1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

#endregion

#region Methods
/// <summary>
/// This function run on Windows service Start event
/// </summary>
/// <param name="args">args</param>
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        timer1 = new Timer();
        this.timer1.Interval = 60000;         //1 Minute=60000, 2 Minute=120000,5 Minute=300000            
        this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        Library.WriteErrorLog(" ============================ ");
        Library.WriteErrorLog(" Windows Service Started. ");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Library.WriteErrorLog(" WCF Service Error Given In OnStart() Is  : " + ex.Message);
    }
}
/// <summary>
/// OnStop event will hit when Windows service Stop
/// </summary>
protected override void OnStop()
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    Library.WriteErrorLog(" Windows Service Stopped. ");

}
/// <summary>
/// timer1_Tick event will call in every Timer Interval as well Window Service Started
/// </summary>
/// <param name="state"></param>
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Library.WriteErrorLog("---------------------------------");
    Library.WriteErrorLog(" Windows Service Timer Ticked and Doing His Job Succcessfully. ");
    Library.WriteErrorLog(" Windows Service Timer Call After 1 Minute. ");
    Library.WriteErrorLog(" WCF Service Call Started. ");
    TimerCalled();
}

/// <summary>
/// This function will called in 'x' time interval. common function will call from OnElapsedTime event
/// </summary>
/// <param name="b"></param>
private void TimerCalled()
{
    try
    {
        Library.WriteErrorLog(" WCF Service Call By Using Windows Service Timer. ");

        DbChecker obj = new DbChecker();
        Boolean bl = obj.checkRecord();

        Library.WriteErrorLog(" Windows Service Timer Call End. ");
        Library.WriteErrorLog("---------------------------------");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Library.WriteErrorLog(" WCF Service Error Given In TimerCalled() Is : " + ex.Message);
    }
}
#endregion
```

When I debug my solution at that time I don't get any error or warning...service run perfectly but I thought may be it is an windows server error

Comment: There is not enough information here to provide a meaningful answer.  Have you checked any logs or the event viewer?  What is your service supposed to do, etc?

Comment: Service is develop for transferring the inventory order to amazon mws account

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to almost anything, depending on the code you've written. The only reasons I can think of for receiving that message are: (1) an unhandled exception; or even a handled one that allows the service process to end; and (2) a service that behaves more like a start-process-finish app: when it starts, it will do a little processing and then end, resulting in that message.

Look for hints along both of those lines in your code.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Johnny for quick response.

Comment: One thing you could try is, if Library.WriteErrorLog is failing for any reason, that would give you what you're seeing: no logs and no help from anywhere; consider trying ultra-simple logging until the thing at least gives you the smallest hint.